# ImportError: Cannot import name 'LoRa'from 'network'

Tags: python, import, pip, raspberry-pi

I was trying to use the LoRa on my Raspberry using Python.

Here is my code:

```
from network import LoRa
import socket
import time
import ubinascii

# Initialise LoRa in LORAWAN mode.
# Europe = LoRa.EU868
lora = LoRa(mode=LoRa.LORAWAN, region=LoRa.EU868, sf=12)

# create an OTAA authentication parameters
dev_eui = ubinascii.unhexlify('DEADDEAD0009DEAB')
app_eui = ubinascii.unhexlify('DEAD25DEAD25DEAD')
app_key = ubinascii.unhexlify('0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF')

# join a network using OTAA (Over the Air Activation)
lora.join(activation=LoRa.OTAA, auth=(dev_eui, app_eui, app_key), timeout=0)

# wait until the module has joined the network
# try each second
while not lora.has_joined():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Not yet joined...')

print("Joined!")

# create a LoRa socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_LORA, socket.SOCK_RAW)

# set the LoRaWAN data rate
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_LORA, socket.SO_DR, 5)

# send some data
while True:
    s.send("This is a message from Armand".encode())
    ##s.setblocking(False)
    time.sleep(1.0)

# get any data received (if any...)
data = s.recv(64)
print(data)
```

But it doesn't even get past the imports when executed with `python3 my_file.py`, I'm getting a `ImportError: cannot import name 'LoRa' from 'network'` (and later I'm getting the same error for ubinascii), whereas I successfully executed the `pip3 install network` command.

I checked the network.py file and it just doesn't mention LoRa anywhere.

Did I even pip-installed the right packages?

Comment: My search revealed that `network` and `ubinascii` are parts of [`Micropython`](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/index.html).

Comment: Yes I'm on their site right now.

Comment: I'm still looking for help, it looks like eveyone is able to run their file right away, I can't find someone focusing on the import part. Can someone explain what pip install I have to do actually pls?

Comment: check the "upip.install() command to install optional packages via a MicroPython interpreter